# how to map id to the values in angular autocomplete

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete

I am using [JustGoscha/allmighty-autocomplete](https://github.com/JustGoscha/allmighty-autocomplete) in my angular app. it requires a data attribute of array elements to fill the list.

the autocomplete directive looks like this.

```
<autocomplete data="services" click-activation="true" ng-model="addServData.serviceSel" on-select="" attr-placeholder="Service Name"></autocomplete>
```

so i get only the servicename field from my services table and filled it.

It works. now When i submit i get the servicename. But i need to post **service_id** instead of **servicename**.

So now how do i attach the ids with the servicenames in this autocomplete directive.

Comment: good question, I haven't worked with autocomplete but given the service name, couldn't you find the service_id by filtering the original array?

Comment: yes I am searching the entire list for id comparing service_name. I thought attaching id with the element would be easy.